# jenkins job recent changes: "No changes in any of the builds."

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I have created jenkins job which takes the created jar file by previous job and install this jar on our test system. This job doesn't do any maven activities it just move the jar to the server where we have our system and extract it there.

When I check the recent changes on this jenkins jobs, It always show the message: "No changes in any of the builds.".

But I need these changes to be sent by email when the test system updated successfully. How to get these changes?

Comment: `No changes in any of the builds` might refer to `no changes in the jenkins configuration` or `no commits has been updates i.e no check-in has been done in the build`. You can use email notification plugin in jenkins this will send the console logs to the specified email id in case of success

Comment: I can see changes/commits in the previous jenkins job

Comment: hmm its mybe because I have configured the wrong branch.. I will need to check this